# Сравнение объектов с использованием делегатов c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Необходимо написать программу, которая будет сортировать объекты при помощи делегатов и выводить их на экран. Ввод данных с клавиатуры, либо загрузкой из txt файла. Данные содержат информацию о студенте, его состоянии здоровья.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Student[] mas = new Student[5];
    int k = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public delegate int CompareHealth(Student o1, Student o2);
    public class Student
    {
        public string name = "";
        public int days = 0;
        public int hemoglobin = 0;
        public Student() { }
        public Student(string name, int days, int hemoglobin)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.days = days;
            this.hemoglobin = hemoglobin;
        }
        public Student(Student s)
        {
            name = s.name;
            days = s.days;
            hemoglobin = s.hemoglobin;
        }
        public string add
        {
            set { name = value; }
            get { return name; }
        }

        private static int CompareName(Student o1, Student o2)
        {
            return (string.Compare(o1.name, o2.name));
        }

        private static int CompareDays(Student o1, Student o2)
        {
            if (o1.days > o2.days) return (1);
            else if (o1.days < o2.days) return (-1);
            else return (0);
        }
        private static int CompareHemoglobin(Student o1, Student o2)
        {
            if (o1.hemoglobin > o2.hemoglobin) return (1);
            else if (o1.hemoglobin < o2.hemoglobin) return (-1);
            else return (0);
        }
        public static CompareHealth SortByName { get { return (new CompareHealth(CompareName)); } }
        public static CompareHealth SortByDays { get { return (new CompareHealth(CompareDays)); } }
        public static CompareHealth SortByHemoglobin { get { return (new CompareHealth(CompareHemoglobin)); } }
    }
    class Students
    {
        private int items = 0; const int n = 10;
        private Student[] students = new Student[n];
        public Student this[int num]
        {
            get { return (students[num - 1]); }
            set { (students[num - 1]) = value; }
        }
        public void Vivod(ListBox h)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < items; i++)
            {
                h.Items.Add(students[i].name);
            }
        }
        public void AddStudent(Student pers)
        {
            if (items < n)
            {
                Student p = new Student(pers);
                students[items++] = p;
            }
        }

        public void SortStudent(CompareHealth compare)
        {
            Student temp = new Student();
            for (int i = 1; i < items; i++)
                for (int j = items - 1; j >= i; j--)
                    if (compare(students[j], students[j - 1]) == -1)
                    { temp = students[j - 1]; students[j - 1] = students[j]; students[j] = temp; }
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (k <= 2)
        {
            mas[k] = new Student(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text);
            comboBox1.Items.Add(mas[k].add);
            k++;
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Students students = new Students();
        students.SortStudent(Student.SortByName);
        students.Vivod(listBox1);     
    }
}
```

На форме есть 3 текстбокса для ввода переменных для каждого объекта, листбокс для вывода результата и две кнопки (для ввода данных и сортировки). Ругается на первую кнопку (не воспринимает int поля) и не работает в принципе, даже если их закомментировать и сравнивать только по имени, результат не выводится. Что нужно сделать для этого? 
Пытался также загружать данные через txt файл, но безуспешно (кода нет, но можете предложить свой ).

Comment: Ругается - приведите текст ошибки.

Comment: Заголовок темы у вас про делегаты. А в теле вопроса вы пишете про неработающий ввод. Не надо так делать. Разбейте тему на несколько вопросов и задайте их отдельно: один - про ввод, другой - про сравнение и делегаты, и т. п.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, поддерживаю. Измените название темы либо суть вопроса

Answer (score 0):

> Ругается на первую кнопку (не воспринимает int поля) и не работает в принципе, даже если их закомментировать и сравнивать только по имени, результат не выводится.

Правильно, потому что TextBox.Text содержит строку - тип string. А у вас конструктор Student с тремя параметрами ожидает целое число для второго и третьего аргументов. Чтобы избежать ошибки, необходимо привести тип string к int:

```
mas[k] = new Student(textBox1.Text, int.Parse(textBox2.Text), int.Parse(textBox3.Text));
```

Но такой подход будет работать только в том случае, если в textBox2.Text и textBox3.Text содержатся только числа. В противном случае вы получите ошибку. Поэтому наилучший способ будет предусмотреть такой вариант событий:

```
int days; int hemo;
if (int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out days) && int.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out hemo))
{
     mas[k] = new Student(textBox1.Text, days, hemo);
     comboBox1.Items.Add(mas[k].add);
     k++;
}
```

Comment: Выдает две пары ошибок:
Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'int.TryParse(string, out int)' has some invalid arguments 
Error 2 Argument 2 must be passed with the 'out' keyword
Это если указать переменные прямо в кнопке (не знаю, можно так или нет)
Если не указывать в кнопке, а только в классе, то ошибка говорит, что не видит эти переменные.

Comment: @AlexDo, подправил код

Comment: Ошибок не выдает, но не сортирует на вторую кнопку

Comment: @AlexDo, при чем тут вторая кнопка? Вы в описании вопроса пишете о проблеме "восприятия int полей". А сейчас спрашиваете про сортировку. Это два совершенно несвязанных друг с другом вопроса. Для разных вопросов принято создавать разные темы

Comment: @AlexDo, к слову сказать, у вас в методе `button2_Click` создается пустой students. Что вы там сортировать пытаетесь?